# Maximo Anywhere 7.6 - Custom Query added in Maximo & app.xml is not displayed in the browser

Tags: maximo-anywhere, oslc

I have created a custom public query in Service Request application in Maximo. The same is downloaded as part of WorkManagement rdf as part of execution of anywhere-rdf-puller.xml.

When the query is added in app.xml in view and resource sections, the same is not visible in the simulator.

I have verified the generated ApplicationUIBuilder.js, I could see the query details but in the debug I couldn't find the query in the *eventcontext* object. I could see only the standard queries.

I have taken standard query as reference to add the custom query in app.xml. Below are the code snippets:

```
<view id="ServiceRequest.MyReportedSR" label="My Service Requests" resource="serviceRequest" showBackButton="true">
            <queries id="ServiceRequest.MyReportedSR_serviceRequest_queries" resource="serviceRequest">
                <query id="ServiceRequest.MyReportedSR_MY_REPORTED_SR" label="My Service Requests" queryBase="MY_REPORTED_SR"/>
                <query id="ServiceRequest.MyReportedSR_HIGH_PRIORITY_SR" label="Urgent Service Requests" queryBase="Z_HighPrioritySRs"/>
   .
   .
                </queries>
   .
   .
    </view>


<resource defaultOrderBy="srnum desc" describedBy="http://jazz.net/ns/ism/work/smarter_physical_infrastructure#ServiceRequest" hasManagedQuery="true" id="serviceRequest" name="serviceRequest" pageSize="200" providedBy="/oslc/sp/WorkManagement"> 
            <attributes id="serviceRequest_attributes">
.
.
</attributes>
<queryBases id="serviceRequest_queryBases">
                <!-- list of query bases the app will rely upon for this resource -->
                <queryBase id="serviceRequest_queryBase_MY_REPORTED_SR" name="MY_REPORTED_SR" queryUri="/oslc/os/oslcsrdetail?savedQuery=MY_REPORTED_SR"/>
                <!-- Added by Karthik For Demo -->
                <queryBase id="serviceRequest_queryBase_HIGH_PRIORITY_SR" name="Z_HighPrioritySRs" queryUri="/oslc/os/oslcsrdetail?savedQuery=Z_HighPrioritySRs"/>
            </queryBases>
        </resource>
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated?

Regards,
Karthik

Comment: This worked after disabling the Anywhere Administration portal in Maximo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the query was not displayed as it is getting overridden by the queries available Anywhere Administration. After disabling the Anywhere Administration, the queries written in the app.xml are visible.